# pinescript indicator to show in chart and in a seperate window

Tags: pine-script

I have a long indicator which gives me buy sell signals and lines in a separate window below the chart. I would like to see the lines in that window, but would like the buy/sell signals to show up in the chart.
Do I need to run this indicator twice once with overlay=true and once with overlay=false, or is there a parameter in the plot function to tell it to display that plot only on the chart?

Thanks in advance
Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you'll have to use two indicators for this. Pine Script at the moment, doesn't support sub-window and overlay indicators combined together.

Comment: That's what I thought, thank you for confirming that.